# Step through C++ code with CLion while PyCharm plugin is enabled

Tags: pycharm, clion

I am having a problem in CLion when the PyCharm plugin is enabled. This is what I do:

1. Run a Python program from the shell. This program creates multiple processes (like workers) in which the Python code calls C++ code that I want to debug.
2. From CLion, attach to the original main Python process.
3. Step through code after C++ breakpoint gets hit in one or more of the created processes.

Usually, this works fine. But if I have the PyCharm plugin enabled, CLion seems to treat the main process differently, and does not hit any of my C++ breakpoints.

Does anyone know how I can get the C++ breakpoints to work, even when the PyCharm plugin is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution that suits my needs, and maybe yours.

This has been tested on Clion 2019.3 with Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3 and GDB.
I have a Python process that spawns a C++ process, and I want to debug both.
The condition is to know the name or PID of the child, and to have time to manually attach to the child process (so like a "wait user key" in the master process, or a breakpoint somewhere after the fork).

According to [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.2/attaching-to-local-process.html?_ga=2.254137807.693430798.1587292001-1321661960.1583918819), on Ubuntu you either need to temporary or permanently allow attaching to a foreign, local process.

> To disable this restriction temporarily, enter the command:
>
> echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
>
> To disable this restriction permanently, open the file
>   /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf for editing and change the line
>   kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1 to kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0. To apply
>   the changes, enter sudo service procps restart or restart your system,
>   at your choice.

Then:

- Create a run configuration for your Python script
- Put breakpoints where needed
- Run the Python script in debug mode
- Wait for it to fork and break on wait condition/breakpoint
- Run->Attach to process...
- type PID or name of C++ child
- voilà, you have control on both master and child processes

Unfortunately, I don't know how to automate it, but that works fine in my project because the two processes exchange messages so when I block one, the other is waiting for data and I have time to manually attach to it.

As a side note, this is probably an answer also for [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674471/clion-debug-c-subprocess-spawned-by-python).