# CLion: Debug C++ subprocess spawned by python

Tags: python, c++, debugging, pycharm, clion

Is there any way in CLion to debug a C++ program that is run from a Python script with `subprocess.Popen`?

I can set breakpoints and debug the Python program, and I can set breakpoints and debug the C++ program if I run it directly, but I can't get my C++ breakpoints to fire when the program is started from Popen.

I tried setting "Python Debugger->Attach to subprocess automatically" while debugging but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: are you on linux, windows, mac... ? On linux you may popen("gdb <you program>")...

Comment: I'm on linux. Running gdb in the popen starts GDB, but CLion isn't aware of this debugging session at all. So I could issue text commands to GDB, but not use CLion's visual debugging

Comment: The same problem, any updates now? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have literally the exact same problem on MacOS. Cannot even attach to the process manually in CLion for it immediately detaches.